# how does this statement works: "static final Comparator<Employee> SENIORITY_ORDER = new Comparator<Employee>() {};"

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I saw the code below on Youtube. I was just wondering how this part of the code works.

```
static final Comparator<Employee> SENIORITY_ORDER = 
                                            new Comparator<Employee>() {
                public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
                    return e2.hireDate().compareTo(e1.hireDate());
                }
        };
```

Could someoen please explain it to me? Thanks in advance for any help!

```
import java.util.*;
public class EmpSort {
    static final Comparator<Employee> SENIORITY_ORDER = 
                                        new Comparator<Employee>() {
            public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
                return e2.hireDate().compareTo(e1.hireDate());
            }
    };

    // Employee database
    static final Collection<Employee> employees = ... ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> e = new ArrayList<Employee>(employees);
        Collections.sort(e, SENIORITY_ORDER);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to ask more specific questions. Tell us what you do and do not understand. (Do you not know what a `Comparator` is? Do you not know how an anonymous class works? And so on... Your question here is so broad.) Help us help you.

Comment: thank you for the advice, will take it on board! :)

Answer (score 1):

The `SENIORITY_ORDER` `Comparator` (used for comparing `Employee`s in the *sort*) is an [Anonymous Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). The linked Java Tutorial reads (in part)

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them if you need to use a local class only once.

Comment: Thank you Elliott!! you have helped me out on numerous occasions in the last few weeks! Can't thank you enough!!

Answer (score 0):

Well as we all konw  .  the Comparator is the rule that how to compare tow Object.

you can come into this Method : Collections.sort(e, SENIORITY_ORDER);

and you will see the answer  you want

```
    public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    Object[] a = list.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator)c);  //this is your rule to compare
    ListIterator i = list.listIterator();
    for (int j=0; j<a.length; j++) {
        i.next();
        i.set(a[j]);
    }
}
```

if your Object not implements comparable so you must have a comparetor
or it's will be a wrong.  The Collections.sort will to call the compare() Method.

Answer (score 0):

```
static final Comparator<Employee> SENIORITY_ORDER = 
                                            new Comparator<Employee>() {
                public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
                    return e2.hireDate().compareTo(e1.hireDate());
                }
        };
```

The statement `static final Comparator<Employee> SENIORITY_ORDER = new Comparator<Employee>(){}`
is creating a reference of the `Comparator<Employee>` interface that points to an instance of an Anonymous Inner Class which implements the `Comparator<Employee>` interface. Hence, you are overrding the `compare()` method of **Comparator Interface** inside your anonymous class.

Inside the `compare()` method you are comparing the **hireDate** attribute of two `Employee` objects using the `compareTo()` method of the `Comparable` interface in java. This method, `compareTo()`, compares the two attributes i.e, **e1.hireDate** and **e2.hireDate**, lexicographically and returns either a positive integer, a negative integer or zero, depending on whether **e2.hireDate** is greater than, less than or equal to **e1.hireDate**.

(HOPE YOU ARE ALREADY AWARE WITH THE CONCEPTS OF **COMPARATOR INTERFACE** AND **NESTED CLASSES** IN JAVA)